# How to clear elastisearch indice from all the elastic nodes in a cluster at once

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I use the following curl command to clear indices from the elasticsearch node.

```
curl -X POST -u user:password "IP:9200/index_name_here/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
'
```

But the problem which Iam facing is when I clear index from one node then it does not clear data from all the other connected elastic nodes and the data again is copied from other nodes to the node which has been cleared from the above command.

All I want is to clear the index(not delete) like the above command from all the elastic nodes in a cluster.

Comment: that is impossible in elasticsearch cluster. when you run this command. you clear data from cluster. not a node

Comment: @SUBHAS PATIL. Please run this via kibana and let me know if there is `_version` equals to 0.       
`GET <index_name>/_search
{
  "_source": "_version", 
  "version": true, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}`

Comment: @AssaelAzran `{"took":45,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}`